# training a model without any weights but just only bias

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, training-data

i was doing some tests using a VGG3 CNN model and i zeroed out all weights and their gradients after every backprop call. i basically allowed only the bias of the model to be trained / updated. what i got was interesting results that i cant per say explain. the accuracy of the model kept on increasing. started off at about 27.12% until after only 10 epochs it reached around 71% accuracy.

this kept me wondering how the accuracy is increasing so significantly without using any weights at all during training. i would love to get some theories and inputs regarding this.

can you actually train a model(not necessarily the best model) without using any weights at all?

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you zero the weights and only use bias then output of the model should be independent of the input. In fact the model only depends on the final layer's bias value. If you implemented it correctly then you should have something akin to a maximum a-priori estimator. I.e. your model predicts the most common class in your training data. That means one of the classes in your training/testing data is overrepresented and your model is always predicting that class.

Comment: Another distinct possibility is that they just made an error in their code and the model is actually learning weights, which is impossible to tell for us since they did not attach any code.